# how to access values in dataset (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, dataset

lm = LinearModel.fit(x, y)

there is lm.Coefficients containing the coefficient values.

E.g.,

> > lm.Coefficients

ans =

```
               Estimate     SE            tStat      pValue     
(Intercept)      -17.637        0.4574    -38.558    5.5217e-252
x1             0.0037939    0.00039008      9.726     6.0697e-22
```

> > get(lm.Coefficients)

ans:

```
Description: ''

VarDescription: {}

Units: {}

DimNames: {'Observations'  'Variables'}

UserData: []

ObsNames: {2x1 cell}

VarNames: {'Estimate'  'SE'  'tStat'  'pValue'}
```

How do I access the estimated coefficients? For example -17.637 in the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Temp = get(lm.Coefficients,'Estimate');
Temp(1:2)

ans = 
    '-17.637'
    '0.0037939'
```